# Fresh Proxmox VE 2.1 installation with defaults can't be reached or pinged

Tags: linux, proxmox

1. I am using the lastest Proxmox VE 2.1.
2. My server has two NICS with a uplink only connected into eth0.
3. My Server is a co-located server utilizing public IPv4 IPs.
4. It is not behind a firewall or any system which monitors traffic.

Via IPKVM I did  a fresh install of Proxmox, I put in the correct IP, Mask, Gateway, and DNS information. The install went perfectly fine with no errors.

Upon completion and rebooting the system:

1. I am unable to reach the web GUI via the browser, it just times out.
2. I am unable to ping the server.
3. I am unable to ping outside to the Internet from within the server. Tried pinging out to 4.2.2.2 and yahoo.com
4. I tried rebooting the server and restarting the network service.

`ifconfig` shows my IP information under `vmbro0` which also has the same MAC address as the `eth0` device.

`eth0` only displays an `IPv6 Scope:Link address`, which I did not setup myself.

This is my first time installing Proxmox, but after searching for a few hours it doesn't seem like anyone else is having the same issue as me from a fresh install with just the defaults. So far the only thing I did was install it.

Also, I know the network cable is good and the IP is good because I was running a Xen XCP server with the same network settings prior to wiping it to install Proxmox.

**Some additional information:**

1. for `pveversion -v` (installed `proxmox-ve_2.1-f9b0f63a-26.iso`)

   ```
   pve-manager: 2.1-1 (pve-manager/2.1/f9b0f63a)
   running kernel: 2.6.32-11-pve
   proxmox-ve-2.6.32: 2.0-66
   ```
2. `netstat -nr` (note: `.136` is my network, and `.137` is my gateway)

   ```
   Destination     - Gateway         -  Genmask
   xxx.xxx.xxx.136 - 0.0.0.0         -  255.255.255.248
   0.0.0.0         - xxx.xxx.xxx.137 -  0.0.0.0
   ```
3. `/etc/network/interfaces`

   ```
   auto lo

   iface lo inet loopback
   auto vmbr0

   iface vmbr0 inet static
                    address xxx.xxx.xxx.138
                    netmask 255.255.255.248
                    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.137
                    bridge_ports eth0
                    bridge_stp off
                    bridge_fd 0
   ```

Comment: Same issue here. I cannot get version 2.1 to install without getting `Starting web server: apache2Syntax error on line 13 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/pve-redirect.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.pem' does not exist or is empty
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
failed!` I've tried over 20 times!

Comment: What does `ifconfig` say? Perhaps your network card is unsupported by the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem and eventually solved it. It's the problem of the LAN we are in. For some reason my LAN doesn't allow me to manually assign IP address when there's a DHCP server out there. The Proxmox installation program use DHCP to detect the network settings and then try to assign the IP manually(by OS) without using DHCP again after reboot.
The solution is to ask the system to perform DHCP again by following commands:

```
dhclient -r vmbr0
dhclient vmbr0
```

Then the problem should be solved.

Comment: Those commands could likely confirm whether DHCP is indeed the problem. But those commands are unlikely to permanently fix the problem. You'd need to edit some configuration files to ensure that the system keeps running a DHCP client - even after the next reboot.

Comment: I agree with you @kasperd, but I've only done this once and don't need to do this again on after reboots.. but it's still necessary to ensure there's a permanent setting, I'm not an expert and hopefully someone else would improve on this.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this resource :

[Host not found cant ping yahoo.com or use aptitude update in proxmox ve?](http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/10134-host-not-found-cant-ping-yahoo-com-or-use-aptitude-update-in-proxmox-ve)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that link doesn't relate to my issue. The issue in that link is a DNS issue with 2 NICs bonded. The issue I am having is absolutely no connectivity while utilizing only 1 NIC.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and:

```
apt-get update and && apt-get upgrade
```

resolved my problem.